# Linking existing MySQL records in new query, PHP/PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
$insert = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO tags (tag_name) VALUES (:tag)');
  $insert->bindParam(':tag', $tag, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  foreach($tags as $tag) {
   $insert->execute();
   $tag_id = $dbh->lastInsertID();
echo $tag_id."+".$photo_id."<br />";
$sql = "INSERT INTO tagrefs (tag_id, photo_id) VALUES (:tag_id,:photo_id)";
$q = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array(':tag_id'=>$tag_id,
                       ':photo_id'=>$photo_id));
  }
```

This particular piece of code inserts tags related to uploaded photos into a table called 'tags'. It links the tag_id to the photo_id in a table called 'tagrefs'. This all works fine, until I use a tag twice. Which is logical, because nothing is inserted (tags are unique, I simply want the entry in 'tagrefs' to list the photo_id for my next photo with tag_id's that already exist)

How do I make it so that my code compares the tags the user put in and compares them, or that the values of existing tags are returned and put into 'tagrefs' properly? Thank you very much in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert-on-duplicate.html), then `lastInsertID()` will return the `AUTO_INCREMENT` field's value of a matched row even if an `UPDATE` is performed instead of an insertion.

To ensure that it also works in versions of MySQL prior to v5.1.12, one can explicitly set the insertion id with MySQL's [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) function:

```
INSERT INTO tags
  (tag_name)
VALUES
  (:tag)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  id = LAST_INSERT_ID(id)
```

Comment: I do not wish to update anything. Changing the tag_id would break it's link to all the other photos. 

If tag_id 1 is tag_name Banana, then updating 1 to 2 would break the tagref record of tag_id 1 linked to the photo of a Banana, which is photo_id 50 for example.

tagrefs:
tag_id | photo_id
1 | 50

Comment: @RudyvanSloten: No data need be updated (that's up to you to specify in the `UPDATE` clause) - the command merely sets the value that will be returned by `lastInsertID()`.  I'm certainly not proposing that the any record's id be altered.  Obviously you will need to have a `UNIQUE` index defined over `tag_name` for this to work.

Comment: $insert = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO tags (tag_name) VALUES (:tag) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE tag_name = $tag');

throws me the error 

Fatal error: Call to a member function bindParam() on a non-object in ***\upload.php on line 77 ($insert->bindParam(':tag', $tag, PDO::PARAM_STR);)

Comment: @RudyvanSloten: You have `$tag` in your SQL, which gives rise to a syntax error.  Just use the SQL exactly as I gave above (replacing the two references to `id` with the actual name of your `AUTO_INCREMENT` column).